# Facing issues in DC/OS Installation in On-Premises

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I am Trying to install DC/OS but facing issues in On-Premises

**Below is the Error Log**

```
Connection to 172.XX.XXX.XX closed.
Starting DC/OS Install Process
Running preflight checks
Checking if DC/OS is already installed: PASS (Not installed)
PASS Is SELinux disabled?
Checking if docker is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking docker version requirement (>= 1.6): PASS (1.11.1)
Checking if curl is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if bash is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if ping is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if tar is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if xz is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if unzip is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if ipset is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if systemd-notify is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if systemd is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking systemd version requirement (>= 200): PASS (219)
Checking if group 'nogroup' exists: PASS 
Checking if port 80 (required by mesos-ui) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 53 (required by mesos-dns) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 15055 (required by dcos-history) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 5050 (required by mesos-master) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 2181 (required by zookeeper) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 8080 (required by marathon) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 3888 (required by zookeeper) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 8181 (required by exhibitor) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 8123 (required by mesos-dns) is in use: PASS 
Checking Docker is configured with a production storage driver: WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
PASS (overlay)
Creating directories under /etc/mesosphere
Creating role file for master
Configuring DC/OS
Setting and starting DC/OS
Job for dcos-setup.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status dcos-setup.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
172.XX.XXX.XX:XX
Connection to 172.XX.XXX.XXX closed.
Starting DC/OS Install Process
Running preflight checks
Checking if DC/OS is already installed: PASS (Not installed)
PASS Is SELinux disabled?
Checking if docker is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking docker version requirement (>= 1.6): PASS (1.11.1)
Checking if curl is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if bash is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if ping is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if tar is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if xz is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if unzip is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if ipset is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if systemd-notify is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking if systemd is installed and in PATH: PASS 
Checking systemd version requirement (>= 200): PASS (219)
Checking if group 'nogroup' exists: PASS 
Checking if port 80 (required by mesos-ui) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 53 (required by mesos-dns) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 15055 (required by dcos-history) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 5050 (required by mesos-master) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 2181 (required by zookeeper) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 8080 (required by marathon) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 3888 (required by zookeeper) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 8181 (required by exhibitor) is in use: PASS 
Checking if port 8123 (required by mesos-dns) is in use: PASS 
Checking Docker is configured with a production storage driver: WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
PASS (overlay)
Creating directories under /etc/mesosphere
Creating role file for slave
Configuring DC/OS
Setting and starting DC/OS
Job for dcos-setup.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status dcos-setup.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
172.XX.XX.XXX:22
```

**As suggested in Error Log we looked into "systemctl status dcos-setup.service" and "journalctl -xe" but not able to determine the actual cause**

```
[root@macXX ~]# systemctl status dcos-setup.service
â dcos-setup.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

[root@macXX ~]# journalctl -xe
May 27 09:40:01 mac58 kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev overlay, type overlay), uses xattr
May 27 09:40:01 mac58 kernel: device veth0db88ce entered promiscuous mode
May 27 09:40:01 mac58 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth0db88ce: link is not ready
May 27 09:40:01 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <warn>  (veth3d6605b): failed to find device 58 'veth3d6605b' with udev
May 27 09:40:01 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <info>  (veth3d6605b): new Veth device (carrier: OFF, driver: 'veth', ifindex: 58)
May 27 09:40:01 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <warn>  (veth0db88ce): failed to find device 59 'veth0db88ce' with udev
May 27 09:40:01 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <info>  (veth0db88ce): new Veth device (carrier: OFF, driver: 'veth', ifindex: 59)
May 27 09:40:01 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <info>  (docker0): bridge port veth0db88ce was attached
May 27 09:40:01 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <info>  (veth0db88ce): enslaved to docker0
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev mqueue, type mqueue), uses transition SIDs
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev proc, type proc), uses genfs_contexts
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev devpts, type devpts), uses transition SIDs
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev sysfs, type sysfs), uses genfs_contexts
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 avahi-daemon[739]: Withdrawing workstation service for veth3d6605b.
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <warn>  (veth3d6605b): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <info>  (veth0db88ce): link connected
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <info>  (docker0): link connected
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth0db88ce: link becomes ready
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth0db88ce) entered forwarding state
May 27 09:40:02 mac58 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth0db88ce) entered forwarding state
May 27 09:40:03 mac58 avahi-daemon[739]: Registering new address record for fe80::4410:e6ff:fedd:be2a on veth0db88ce.*.
May 27 09:40:17 mac58 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth0db88ce) entered forwarding state
May 27 09:47:10 mac58 kernel: traps: python3[17232] general protection ip:7f2be234423 sp:7f2beceb0394 error:0 in libc-2.22.s
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth0db88ce) entered disabled state
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <info>  (veth0db88ce): link disconnected
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <warn>  (veth3d6605b): failed to find device 58 'veth3d6605b' with udev
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <info>  (veth3d6605b): new Veth device (carrier: OFF, driver: 'veth', ifindex: 58)
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <info>  (docker0): link disconnected (deferring action for 4 seconds)
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 abrt-server[17352]: Executable '/opt/mesosphere/packages/python--e3169ded66609d3cb4055a3f9f8f0b1113a557
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 abrt-server[17352]: 'post-create' on '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-05-27-09:47:10-17214' exited with 1
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 abrt-server[17352]: Deleting problem directory '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2016-05-27-09:47:10-17214'
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 avahi-daemon[739]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::4410:e6ff:fedd:be2a on veth0db88ce.
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth0db88ce) entered disabled state
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 avahi-daemon[739]: Withdrawing workstation service for veth3d6605b.
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 avahi-daemon[739]: Withdrawing workstation service for veth0db88ce.
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <warn>  (veth3d6605b): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <info>  (docker0): bridge port veth0db88ce was detached
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <info>  (veth0db88ce): released from master docker0
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <warn>  (veth0db88ce): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 kernel: device veth0db88ce left promiscuous mode
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 kernel: docker0: port 1(veth0db88ce) entered disabled state
May 27 09:47:11 mac58 docker[10803]: time="2016-05-27T09:47:11.828750505+05:30" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.23/cont
May 27 09:47:16 mac58 NetworkManager[776]: <info>  (docker0): link disconnected (calling deferred action)
```

**Your Help is Highly Appreciated!!!...Thank you**

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No I did not found the solution infact we switch from Mesosphere DC/OS to Mesos

Comment: try to contact support@mesosphere.com i got few help but unfortunate due to time limitation we switched to mesos